# Can we pass stored procedure in @query parameter of sp_db_sendmail procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Heyy Guys,

Can we pass stored procedure in `@query` parameter of `sp_db_sendmail` procedure?

I am doing the same it shows error every time.

Error:

> Msg 22050, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
>   Error formatting query, probably invalid parameters
>   Msg 14661, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_send_dbmail, Line 504
>   Query execution failed: Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Server myServer, Line 1
>   Could not find stored procedure 'sp_something'.

Please help

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx you can supply a query to @query parameter try to do your 'exec sp_something' there.

Comment: Sorry Guys,

I have passed wrong procedure name that's why i was unable to call procedure in sp_db_sendmail

**The fact is you can pass Store Procedure as @query parameter in sp_db_sendmail procedure [same as query].**